# Creating a new item or updating an existing item

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Something about my code just doesn't seem right.  It feels cumbersome and not very logical.

Could someone put me out of my misery and let me know that I wrote this bit ok?

It's pretty simple, when the page loads, it is checking to see if the user is trying to update an existing book or create a new book.

Here is the code:

```
Public Property modID As Int32

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim bookID = Request.QueryString("bookID")
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookID) Then
        newBook = False
    Else
        newBook = True
        Create()   'create a new book
        bookID = modID.ToString
    End If

    If Not newBook Then
        commitData()   'saves data on form
    End If

    If Not IsPostBack And Not newBook Then
        Page.DataBind()
        populateControls()    'populate my dropdown lists and radio/checkbox controls
        populateDatasets()    'load datasets to be used later
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub Create()
    'create a new book
    newBook = False
    Using dbcon As New SqlConnection(DBUtilities.ConnectionStringDefault)
        dbcon.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(CreateSQL, dbcon)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@authorID", currentUser))
        modID = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Int32)
    End Using
    navmod = NavbookFactory.Getbook(CInt(modID))
    populateNewBook()
End Sub
```

Comment: This kind of question (critiques of code) should be posted on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), not here.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't even know of that site -thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the not and the extra if

```
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bookID) Then
        newBook = True
        Create()   'create a new book
        bookID = modID.ToString        
    Else
        newBook = False
        commitData()
    End If
```